# BOOST tutorial on multithreaded client?

Tags: c++, boost

Is there any good tutorials about a multithreaded client except the one on the BOOST website?
A multithreaded client that can handle sending data to server whilist also printing what the server is sending it at the same time.
For example: a thread for what the user is inputting and sending it to server, and a thread that handles socket and receives info from server and prints it on cout.

Comment: are you asking about using asio or something else? can you provide the link of the example on the Boost website, so that people know what you are talking about.

Comment: yes, io_service.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you gave is an excellent guide on how to use the boost::asio library.
You will be able to do what you want without multiple threads, once you understand how it works.

The idea of asio (asynchronous IO) is to call you back once an operation is completed by the io_service object. Whenever you call aync_xxx, you pass to it a function pointer (or functor), which will be called once the operation is done. In this way, you don't have to have a separate thread blocking on polling IOs.

for example, you want to read a message from the server, once it is done. call do_something(Message& msg). That exactly what example code did.

Because TCP is a stream based protocol with no natural message boundary, you have to define your own message format on it.  In the example, it defines a chat_message class for this purpose.

To read messages, a client follows these steps, each of which is triggered as a result of callback after the previous async_xxx operation is done. it also rely on the fact that an async_read is complete only when exact number of bytes specified is read, or when an error occurs.

1. call async_connect, pass handle_connect as its callback.
2. handle_connect calls async_read, pass handle_read_header as its callback
3. handle_read_header calls async_read, pass handle_read_body as its callback.
4. handle_read_body will eventually call async_read, pass handle_read_header as its callback, so that the procedure repeat itself for the next message.

notice that, In the sample, it did "cout.write..." in step 4, before it invoke async_read.  **all you need to do is to replace the "cout.wirte.." part with your do_something(msg).**

the writing part follows a similar chain of callbacks, the only difference is that the chain breaks when no more message to write, hence we need to check the condition and restart it.